# "availability date" on itunes connect new interface?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is anyone else having problems with "availability date" set on itunes connect? Here is what happened to me this time: I set "automatically release on 10/29" when submitting for review, as we usually do to plan an automatic rolling relase on release date. However the app has been approved today and it is now in "Pending developer release" state which is what normally happens if you had selected "Manually release". Anyone having the same issue?
I also tried changing the date in "Availability" under "Pricing and availability" tab but when I save the date goes back to today...

Is it an issue on the new interface? anyone seeing the same?

Comment: Here feedback from apple :

"This issue behaves as intended based on the following:

There is no more app level availability date. If you want to remove your app from sale now that it is live you can set the availability to ‘remove from sale’ also for subsequent versions, you can set the release of version updates to a specific date and time in the version release section."
 
I dont understand why my previous answer was marked "Not An Answer"!

Comment: Well, I have a ticket open with APple and they said their engineering is investigating. The problem is that I can't set the availability date under "price and availability" in the release section. Plus I am not trying to remove the app from sale, I am trying to have the first approved build released only at a certain date. This has always worked before. PS I didn't mark your answer "not an answer"

Comment: @StefanoMelucci I'm having the same issue. Did you get any further feedback from engineering?

Comment: same issue here any updates ?

Answer (score 0):

This is from a 2015 wwdc talk

http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/302

"We are adding a third new option, which is called Scheduled Release, and for this, you can choose the date and time when your app will move through processing for App Store. So just like manual release, after it's approved, it's going to go into Pending Developer Release, but instead of you logging into iTunes Connect, we'll move it for you at that given date and time."

This is from support regarding automatic release having a "Release this version" button.

"If you elect your app to be automatically released at a predetermined date, the option to release the app version manually will still be present. This is in the event you’d like to release the app earlier than anticipated."